# Use groovy category in groovy shell

Tags: groovy, dsl, groovyshell

I am working under some DSL using Groovy categories and I would like to find a way to use my DSL with groovy shell without explicitly writing `use(MyCategory){ myObject.doSomething() }` for each command.

For example, suppose I have the following toy category:

```
class MyCategory {
    static Integer plus(Integer integer, String string){
        return integer + Integer.valueOf(string)
    }
}
```

Then, I can use this category in `groovysh` in the following way:

```
groovy> use(MyCategory){ 2 + '3' } //gives 5
```

So, is there any way to set up `MyCategory` globally for all `groovysh` commands, so it will not be necessary to each time wrap my commands in `use(MyCategory) { ... }`? For example:

```
groovy> useGlobally(MyCategory); //call something like this only once
groovy> 2 + '3' //automatically uses MyCategory and gives 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the category is to close the scope of metaprogramming. Why not use `metaClass` in this case?

```
groovy:000> class MyCategory {
groovy:001>     static Integer plus(Integer integer, String string){
groovy:002>         return integer + Integer.valueOf(string)
groovy:003>     }
groovy:004> }
===> true
groovy:000> Integer.metaClass.mixin MyCategory
===> null
groovy:MyCategory@131fa4b> 2 + '4'
===> 6
groovy:MyCategory@131fa4b>
```

---

**Update**: With a lot of methods, you can iterate through the first parameters of the static methods and mixin them into the respective parameter type class.

```
class MyCategory {
    static global() {
        MyCategory.metaClass.methods
            .findAll { it.isStatic() && !it.name.startsWith("__") && it.name != "global" }
            .each { it.nativeParameterTypes[0].mixin MyCategory }
    }

    static Integer plus(Integer integer, String string){
        return integer + Integer.valueOf(string)
    }

    static String yell(String a, times) {
      a.toUpperCase() * times + "!!!"
    }
}


MyCategory.global()


assert "a".yell(3) == "AAA!!!"
assert 2+'3' == 5
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I want to find. But if `MyCategory` contains a lot of overriding for different classes, then I need to specify `mixin` for each class manually (like for `Integer`). Is there any way to do this automatically?