# Groovy : Is it possible to make a dynamic property with this?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is it possible to transform the following groovy request in a one-line dynamic property?
That question is for using the result in a SOAPui request without using a groovy script.
Because i have a lot of differents dates to put in my request, and also in my assertions.

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
use (TimeCategory) {
    date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date() -5.month)
}
```

I would like to have a dynamic property that i could, off course, change. For example:

```
<ech:date1>${Today - 5 month}</ech:date1>
<ech:date2>${Today - 4 month}</ech:date2>
<ech:date3>${Today - 3 week}</ech:date3>
```

EDIT : **More information**

Actually, i have a dynamic property that give me today's date, minus or plus x days, that i can put in a xml request in SOAPui:

[Here, it return me today's date plus twenty days]

```
${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()+20)}
```

Sample application:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ech="http://echange.service.open.bodet.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ech:importRequests01>
         <ech:Requests01ToImport>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ech:Request01>

               <ech:requestDate>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date() +20)}</ech:requestDate>

               <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
            </ech:Request01>
         </ech:Requests01ToImport>
      </ech:importRequests01>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, i would like to have a same thing, but for asking today's date minus/plus x month...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find this, that give me for example "2014-7-10":**

**usable from groovy** :

```
(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 0) +"-"+(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) +1)+"-"+(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE) - 0)
```

**Usable from XML, and also from SoapUI test request :**

```
${= (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 0) +"-"+(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) +1)+"-"+(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE) - 0)}
```

---

With this, i can specify "MONTH -5" or "MONTH +2".
As i use the same for the YEAR or the DAY, i can do the same for them.

**WARN : Don't forget that in gregorian calendar, the first month, january, is equal to 0.**
That's why i put "...get(Calendar.MONTH) **+1**..."

Answer (score 1):

see the exellent [post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html) for details:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

Date now = new Date()
now.clearTime()

Date nowMin5Month = now.updated( MONTH:now[ MONTH ] - 5 )
String nowMin3Week = now.updated( WEEK_OF_YEAR:now[ WEEK_OF_YEAR ] - 3 ).format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i can't put this on a test request! if i take your solution, like mine, , i have to pass through a groovy script...that i don't want to

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Soap UI, but does [mixing the Category into the respective types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23894819/563890) help?

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

class TimeCategoryMixer {
    static global() {
        TimeCategory.metaClass.methods
            .findAll { it.isStatic() && !it.name.startsWith("__") && it.name != "global" }
            .each { it.nativeParameterTypes[0].mixin TimeCategory }
    }
}

TimeCategoryMixer.global()

def d = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2000-01-01')

assert d - 5.month == Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '1999-08-01')
```

---

**Update**

As per your update, what about this:

```
b="${use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2000-01-01') - 5.month} }"

assert b == Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '1999-08-01').toString()
```

I think SoapUI will be happy with something like this:

```
<ech:requestDate>${=use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2000-01-01') - 5.month}}</ech:requestDate>
```

Comment: Hi, i add more details to my original question. Maybe i described a bad problem...

Comment: it doesn't works on Soapui xml Request. I don't know if it's possible to insert "groovy.time.TimeCategory". But if it works, the other problem is that the date will not be time-varying, 'cause the date is written on the variable...I need to have a variable that take today's date (plus or minus x month), because i will pass this tests several times on a year. And i don't want this to be referenced to a date. Tell me if it's not clear.

Comment: Can you add a method to the Date object, using metaprogramming, which abstracts that logic and call it on soapui?